# How to modify inputKeys for a custom CIFilter?

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a custom CIFilter. So far this filter just brightens an image, its not what I actually want, but I'm doing it to see if I can get it working. Although the filter works with a set value of inputBlurRadius, I don't know how to change it so that the user can change the value. Here is the custom filter.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

public class CustomFilter: CIFilter {
    var inputImage: CIImage?
    private var kernel: CIColorKernel!
    var inputBrightness: CGFloat = 0.4

override public var outputImage: CIImage!
{
    guard let inputImage = inputImage
        else
    {
        return nil
    }

    let extent = inputImage.extent

    let blur = createCustomKernel4().apply(
        withExtent: inputImage.extent,
        roiCallback:
        {
            (index, rect) in
            return rect
    },
        arguments: [inputImage, inputBrightness as AnyObject])

    return blur!.cropping(to: extent)
}

func createCustomKernel4() -> CIColorKernel {
    let kernelString =
        "kernel vec4 brightenEffect (sampler src , float k) { \n " +
            " vec4 currentSource = sample (src, samplerCoord (src));" +
            "currentSource.rgb = currentSource.rgb + k * currentSource.a;" +
            "return currentSource; \n " +
    "}"
    return CIColorKernel(string: kernelString)!
    //brigtens an image
}
}


 class CustomFiltersVendor: NSObject, CIFilterConstructor
{
     static func registerFilters()
     {
    CIFilter.registerName(
        "CustomFilter",
        constructor: CustomFiltersVendor(),
        classAttributes: [
            kCIAttributeFilterCategories: ["CustomFilters"]
        ])
}

func filter(withName name: String) -> CIFilter?
{
    switch name
    {
    case "CustomFilter":
        return CustomFilter()

    default:
        return nil
    }
}
}
```

In the file that I want to use it in, I have

```
let filter3 = CustomFilter()
filter3.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
filter3.inputKeys
let outputImage = filter3.outputImage!
```

I do see inputBrightness in the inputKeys, but I have no idea how to modify it? How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late answer, but I just ran across this question. If you haven't, subclass `CIFilter`.

Your kernel code implies that you wish to pass a value for `float k`. Let's say you wish to call it `inputBrightnessFactor`. Here's what you need in your subclass:

```
class CustomFilter:CIFilter {

    let kernel = CIColorKernel(source: 
        "kernel vec4 brightenEffect (sampler src , float k) { \n " +
            "vec4 currentSource = sample (src, samplerCoord (src));" +
            "currentSource.rgb = currentSource.rgb + k * currentSource.a;" +
            "return currentSource; \n " +
        "}")
    var inputImage:CIImage!
    var inputBrightnessFactor:Float = 1

    override var attributes: [String : Any] {
        return [
            kCIAttributeFilterDisplayName: "My Custom Filter",

            "inputImage": [kCIAttributeIdentity: 0,
                           kCIAttributeClass: "CIImage",
                           kCIAttributeDisplayName: "Image",
                           kCIAttributeType: kCIAttributeTypeImage],

            "inputBrightnessFactor": [kCIAttributeIdentity: 0,
                                      kCIAttributeClass: "NSNumber",
                                      kCIAttributeDisplayName: "Brightness Factor",
                                      kCIAttributeDefault: 0,
                                      kCIAttributeMin: 0,
                                      kCIAttributeSliderMin: 0,
                                      kCIAttributeSliderMax: 1,
                                      kCIAttributeType: kCIAttributeTypeScalar]
        ]
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    override func setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String) {
        switch key {
            case "inputImage":
                inputImage = value as! CIImage
            case "inputBrightnessFactor":
                inputBrightnessFactor = value as! Float
            default:
                break
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override var outputImage: CIImage {
        return kernel!.apply(extent: inputImage.extent, arguments: [inputImage as Any, inputBrightnessFactor as Any])!
    }
}
```

Two key things of note:

- You override the `attributes` to register display values for the filters and attributes, and give the attributes their defaults.
- You override the `setValue(forKey:)` to allow you to use it like any other filter.

Usage (make sure you run `CustomFilters.registerFilters()` first):

```
let myFactor:Float = 0.4
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CustomFilter")
filter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
filter.setValue(myFactor, forKey: "inputBrightnessFactor")
let myOutputImage = filter?.outputImage
```

Note that you now treat your kernel like any other `CIFilter`.

Hopefully you already got things working, but if not, the should do it.

Comment: I got it working, but thanks for writing up a solution!