# Using setValue(_, forKey:) and value(forKey:) with CIFilter

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, cifilter, setvalue

I have adapted code from this Swift 3 fork of [Filterpedia](https://github.com/Norod/Filterpedia) into a new single view app. The same code that works in the Filterpedia project linked works fine but crashes in my version.

This code causes an `NSException` in my project but not the project it was copied from:

```
currentFilter.setValue(640, forKey: "inputHeight")
```

The exception is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<PerlinMetal.MetalPerlinNoise 0x101612c50> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key inputHeight.'
```

In my project currentFilter is defined as:

```
fileprivate var currentFilter = MetalPerlinNoise()
```

`MetalPerlinNoise` is the identical class from Filterpedia, and inherits from `CIFilter`.

I also get an `NSException` trying to access values such as:

```
// inputKeys is defined in CIFilter:
open var inputKeys: [String] { get }

for inputKey in inputKeys {
    var bufferValue = value(forKey: inputKey) as? Float
}
```

This code also works in Filterpedia, but not my adaptation. It fails with a similar NSException as above:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<PerlinMetal.MetalPerlinNoise 0x137e073c0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key inputWidth.'
```

EDIT:

Code calling value(_, forKey:) is identical as the Filterpedia fork:

```
override var outputImage: CIImage!
{
    if textureInvalid()
    {
        self.textureDescriptor = nil
    }

    if let imageFilter = self as? MetalImageFilter,
        let inputImage = imageFilter.inputImage
    {
        return imageFromComputeShader(width: inputImage.extent.width,
            height: inputImage.extent.height,
            inputImage: inputImage)
    }

    if let generatorFilter = self as? MetalGeneratorFilter
    {
        //This is the line calling the code that crashes attempting to access values by key:
        return imageFromComputeShader(width: generatorFilter.outputSize.width,
            height: generatorFilter.outputSize.height,
            inputImage: nil)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Probably due to changes in [Obj-C Inference](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0160-objc-inference.md). You can add `@objcMembers` to the class or go to your build setting and turn on `Swift 3 @objc Inference`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't think that is it. I checked the `@objc Inference` settings and they are the same in both projects and `@objcMembers` isn't used at all in the other project.

Comment: I'm assuming that you are using Swift 4? First, thanks for giving me the fork - I hadn't seen this. While (so far) it upgraded successfully to Swift 4 and works on the first few filters, it is very... unstable. I wanted to see how a custom filter's `inputKeys` code has changed because my last working copy was in Swift 2. I'll check out your issue along with mine - after I get the table control able to scroll to that filter. :-) We may both have the same issue, as we both are looking at a custom filter's `inputKey` dictionary/array.

Comment: I have my keys working. Could you post a bit more code? Specifically, **your** code - not any Filterpedia fork - that overrides the `attributes` property in `MetalPerlinNoise` (I might suggest the full class), and (b) the "calling" code generating this error.

Comment: My entire MetalPerlinNoise class is literally identical as the from the Filterpedia fork. The code calling `value(_, forKey:)` is also identical, but added it to an edit of the question above.

Comment: I was going through [cifilter] tagged questions and ran across this one. If you are still trying to get `setValue(forKey:)` to work, check out my answer here - I think it will help. TL;DR... you need to (1) set up your custom `CIFilter` correctly, (2) subclass `CIFilterConstrctor`, and (3) run the `registerFilters()` in the subclass you created in step 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44571898/how-to-modify-inputkeys-for-a-custom-cifilter/48909304#48909304